# acts_as_relation for multiple inheritance rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, multiple-inheritance, eager-loading

I am using acts_as_relation [link](https://github.com/hzamani/acts_as_relation) gem for implementing multiple inheritance between models. Which is as follows

```
# model/m.rb
class M < ActiveRecord::Bas
  has_many :m_sgs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :m_sgs
end

# model/m_sg.rb
class MSg < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :m
  acts_as_superclass
end

# model/m_sg_w.rb
class MSgW < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :m_sg
end

# model/m_sg_b.rb
class MSgB < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :m_sg
end
```

Everything works fine, but queries are very slow as When I trying to access like this

```
<% M.all.each do |s| %>
  <% if s.as_m_sg_type.to_s == 'MSgW' %>
    <tr><td width="15%">mwid</td><td><%= s.specific.mwid %></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="15%">mwuserid</td><td><%= s.specific.mwuser_id %></td></tr>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

I checked on logs, whenever I made s,specific request it sends a new Select request that return only 1 row, which is wrong coz by default "acts_as_relation" provides auto_joins. So please help me to improve this coz data retrieving is very slow

Comment: In your code-sample I see you iterate over `M`, how do you iterate over the related `MSg` ? (and i sincerely hope that are not your real class-names).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `:auto_join` feature is for queries going the other way (from the children up to the parent). You can give `includes` a try when you load your `M` records:

```
@m = M.includes(:m_sgs).all
```

or maybe

```
@m = M.includes(m_sgs: :as_m_sg).all
```

### Update

Here's the code with the associations that I think the gem is adding:

```
#model/m.rb
class M < ActiveRecord::Bas
  has_many :m_sgs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :m_sgs
end

#model/m_sg.rb
class MSg < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :m

  acts_as_superclass
  # belongs_to :as_m_sg, polymorphic: true
end

#model/m_sg_w.rb
class MSgW < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :m_sg
  # has_one :m_sg, as: :as_m_sg, class_name: MSg, autosave: true, validate: false, dependent: destroy
  # default_scope -> { joins(:m_sg) }
end

#model/m_sg_b.rb
class MSgB < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :m_sg
  # has_one :m_sg, as: :as_m_sg, class_name: MSg, autosave: true, validate: false, dependent: destroy
  # default_scope -> { joins(:m_sg) }
end
```

Comment: Yes, It should work without includes as per documentations but I already tried this solution before...it did not work...

Comment: auto_join only applies when you query for a child class (e. g. `MSgW.first`).

Comment: ok...so is the problem...i did not know this..but how it can be solved...?

Comment: Did you try my second includes example? Based on the code of the gem, I think that will work. If you're using MySQL, that should give you one query per table.

Comment: Yes, I tried second one as well and seems like not working, and I am using MySQL but it should return me an array or Object..for second case just want to know....

Comment: I added some sample code that might help make the problem clearer. You can also try running `M.includes(m_sgs: :as_m_sg).to_sql` and see if the returned query looks right.

Comment: I tried both solutions again and in first I get list of empty arrays in both cases